# How to get second item property from itemslist knowing the first one

Tags: c#

I have a `Server class`:

```
public class CsServerInfo
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and a `ServerList` :

```
public class ServerList
{
    public List<CsServerInfo> serverdata { get; set; }
}
```

Now from the `ServerList` which is collection of servers I want to get the `ip` property (`string`) of an `Item` where I know the `name` property.

Basically I want to say get me the `ip` property of an item where `name="newserver"`.

I know I can search for name property like this:

```
var item = serverList.serverdata.Select(p => p.name == server.Text);
```

but I have no idea how to get to the second property. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Where` clause first to filter all the ones that you want, then use a `Select` on those items to get the `ip`

```
var item = serverList.serverdata
                     .Where(p => p.name == server.Text)
                     .Select(p => p.ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a projection using the `Select` method, after having filter you list:

```
var item = serverList.serverdata
                     .Where(p => p.name == server.Text)
                     .Select(p=>ip);
```

You could also try this:

```
var server = serverList.serverdata
                       .FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == server.Text);

if(server!=null)
{
    // the server found
    var ip = server.ip;
}
```

Note, however, that if there are more than one servers with the same name, the above approach would return the first found.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that you say "searches for the name property" doesn't actually work. This code:

```
var item = serverList.serverdata.Select(p => p.name == server.Text);
```

returns a list of booleans indicating whether each item in the list matched your criteria.

This similar code actually gets you what you want: the first item that matches the name you specified:

```
var item = serverList.serverdata.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == server.Text);
```

Then you can just access the property:

```
var ip = item.ip;
```

Note that `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if no matching item is found - so you should check whether `item == null` before trying to access it.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
serverList.serverdata.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == server.Text).ip;
```

Or. Once you select it. You have selected it and that is now in var x right?

So I think you can access it in the var x. Something like..

```
MessageBox.Show(x.ip);
```

Comment: `Where` will return an `IEnumerable`, not a single item

Comment: @Jonesopolis Oops! Thanks I meant to do FirstOrDefault not where!